# Google Map Markers are not visible. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This Below code is working fine if I click the first checkbox & then click the other both for selecting & unselecting.
 It seems main problem is `if(document.getElementById('mapCheck').checked)` - this line.

If I remove this line then markers will be only added to the map but can't be removed based on check property of checkbox(obviously because there will be no if else condition to check the checkbox checked property).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
        </script>

        <!-- For dynamic table -->

        <style>

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        table#appraiserTable tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        table#appraiserTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
           background-color:#fff;
        }
        table#appraiserTable th {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
        </style>

        <script>
        var lat=[10,20,30,40];
        var lon=[10,20,30,40];
        var appraiserName=["A1","A2","A3","A4"];
        var appraiserLocation=["L1","L2","L3","L4"];
        document.write("<table id=appraiserTable border=1 style=margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;>")
        document.write("<tr><th>Select</th><th>Appraiser Name</th><th>Location</th></tr>");
          for (row=0; row<lat.length; row++) {
             document.write("<tr>")
             for (col=1; col<=3; col++) {
                if(col==1)
                   document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='mapCheck' name='myTextEditBox' value='checked' onchange='showOrHideMarkers("+lat[row]+","+lon[row]+");'/></td>")
                if(col==2)
                   document.write("<td width='200'>"+appraiserName[row]+"</td>")
                if(col==3)
                   document.write("<td width='350'>"+appraiserLocation[row]+"</td>")
              }
              document.write("</tr>")
         }
         document.write("</table>")

        var map;
        var markers=[];


        //load all markers to an array
        function loadMarkers(){
        for(var i=0;i<lat.length;i++)
        {
        var markerCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]);

          var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          position: markerCenter,
          });
        markers.push(marker);
        }
        }


        // Shows or Hides markers currently in the array.
        function showOrHideMarkers(latitude,longitude) {

        var index;
          for(var i=0;i<lat.length;i++)
          {
             if(lat[i]==latitude && lon[i]==longitude)
             {
                 index=i;
                 break;
             }
          }

        //User selects the check box to see the marker in Google Map
        if(document.getElementById('mapCheck').checked)
        {
        console.log(latitude+" : "+longitude+" : "+index)
        markers[index].setMap(map);
        }

        //User unselects the checkbox not to see the marker
        else
        {
        console.log(latitude+" : "+longitude+" : "+index)
        markers[index].setMap(null);
        }

        }


        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
        //Initializing the Map 
        function initialize()
        {
        var mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:5,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        loadMarkers();
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
        <style>
        div.absolute {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 3px solid #8AC007;
        }
        </style>
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;" class="absolute"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few mistakes. First:

```
if(document.getElementById('mapCheck').checked)
```

will not work. You have 4 checkboxes and you are using getElementById which will get the first one with the id. Basically only first checkbox will work this way.

Second. While you can use the SetMap, you are better off by using setVisible on the markers.

Good luck with your project. Here is the updated working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

        <!-- For dynamic table -->

        <style>
            table, th, td {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            th, td {
                    padding: 5px;
                    text-align: center;
            }
            table#appraiserTable tr:nth-child(even) {
                    background-color: #eee;
            }
            table#appraiserTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
                 background-color:#fff;
            }
            table#appraiserTable th {
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            var lat=[10,20,30,40];
            var lon=[10,20,30,40];
            var appraiserName=["A1","A2","A3","A4"];
            var appraiserLocation=["L1","L2","L3","L4"];
            document.write("<table id=appraiserTable border=1 style=margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;>")
            document.write("<tr><th>Select</th><th>Appraiser Name</th><th>Location</th></tr>");
                for (row=0; row<lat.length; row++) {
                     document.write("<tr>")
                     for (col=1; col<=3; col++) {
                            if(col==1)
                                 document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='mapCheck' name='myTextEditBox' value='checked' onchange='showOrHideMarkers(this,"+lat[row]+","+lon[row]+");'/></td>")
                            if(col==2)
                                 document.write("<td width='200'>"+appraiserName[row]+"</td>")
                            if(col==3)
                                 document.write("<td width='350'>"+appraiserLocation[row]+"</td>")
                        }
                        document.write("</tr>")
             }
             document.write("</table>")

            var map;
            var markers=[];


            //load all markers to an array
            function loadMarkers(){
            for(var i=0;i<lat.length;i++)
            {
            var markerCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]);

                var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerCenter,
                });
            marker.setMap(map);
            marker.setVisible(false)
            markers.push(marker);
            }
            }


            // Shows or Hides markers currently in the array.
            function showOrHideMarkers(o,latitude,longitude) {
            var index;
                for(var i=0;i<lat.length;i++)
                {
                     if(lat[i]==latitude && lon[i]==longitude)
                     {
                             index=i;
                             break;
                     }
                }

            //User selects the check box to see the marker in Google Map
            if(o.checked)
            {
            console.log('showing: '+index)
            markers[index].setVisible(true)
            }

            //User unselects the checkbox not to see the marker
            else
            {
            console.log('hiding: '+index)
            markers[index].setVisible(false)
            }

            }


            var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
            //Initializing the Map 
            function initialize()
            {
            var mapProp = {
                center:myCenter,
                zoom:5,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

            map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

            loadMarkers();
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
        <style>
            div.absolute {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 10px;
                    right: 10px;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 100px;
                    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;" class="absolute"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I add an animation in the markers (i.e adding `animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE` in `loadMarkers` function `marker` object).
Then if I select a checkbox & unselect it and again select it the animation stopped working. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Just put markers[index].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); in front of markers[index].setVisible(true);